# ReSharper: "Add to abbreviations list" missing

Tags: resharper

I have a reasonably fresh VS2010 + RS8.1 installation but for some reason the option to add an abbreviation to the abbreviations list is missing :-( So if I AltEnter eg. "ClientID" I would expect to get the option to add "ID" to the abbreviations list (along with the option to rename it to "ClientId" of course). But I don't.

Anyone know how to reenable this again?

edit: I found out where to maintain the list manually: ReSharper - Options - Code editing - C# - Naming style

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They moved it...

When you hit Alt+Enter, go to "Options for 'Inconsistent Naming' inspections" | Add 'ID' to the abbreviation list ...

Comment: When I hit Alt+Enter nothing happens :-(